# SQRT returning no value scss

Tags: sass, compass-sass, compass

Maybe the title is not so accurate but I am having a problem with sqrt function. This is the function

```
$red-magic-number: 241;
$green-magic-number: 691;
$blue-magic-number: 68;
$brightness-divisor: $red-magic-number + $green-magic-number + $blue-magic-number;

@function brightness($color) {
    $red-component: red($color);
    $green-component: green($color);
    $blue-component: blue($color);

    $number: sqrt((($red-component * $red-component * $red-magic-number) + ($green-component * $green-component * $green-magic-number) + ($blue-component * $blue-component * $blue-magic-number)) / $brightness-divisor);
    @return 100% * ($number / 255);
}

@function text-color($color, $light:#fff, $dark:#000) {
    @if brightness($color) < 65% {
        @return $light;
    } @else {
        @return $dark;
    }
}
```

Part where it fails

```
$number: sqrt((($red-component * $red-component * $red-magic-number) + ($green-component * $green-component * $green-magic-number) + ($blue-component * $blue-component * $blue-magic-number)) / $brightness-divisor);

@return 100% * ($number / 255);
```

Error:

```
Error: Undefined operation: "100% times sqrt(11707.92)/255".
```

So $number doesn't return a number but the whole function.

How should I fix this?

Comment: BTW: Checked this it worked on codepen so I guess it's the current sass version that fails..

Comment: The sqrt function is part of Compass.  If it is not available, that means you aren't actually using Compass.  Note that Codepen and Sassmeister always compile with Compass rather than vanilla Sass.

Comment: I am using compass. My whole project uses Compass.

Comment: I  had to update my compass! Thats why it worked on my other computer.